# Let $l=lcm(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ be the least common multiple of a sequence of integers. How we call the sequence $(\frac{l}{a_1},\frac{l}{a_2},\ldots)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking for the appropriate concept that describes the following situation:

Let $l$ be the least common multiple of a sequence or vector of integers: $l=lcm(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$.

How do we call the sequence or vector $(\frac{l}{a_1},\frac{l}{a_2},\ldots,\frac{l}{a_n})$?

Can we express this by the use of standardized algebraic/analytic means. Does for this exist a term?

One simple example: Let us consider the sequence $(10,4,6)$ and $lcm(10,4,6)=60$. How we call the sequence $(6,15,10)$?

Comment: Reciprocating your example yields $$\begin{align}& \frac{1}{10},\ \ \frac{1}4,\ \  \ \frac{1}6\\[.4em] =\  &\frac{\color{#c00}6}{60},\ \frac{\color{#c00}{15}}{60},\ \frac{\color{#c00}{10}}{60}\end{align}\qquad$$

hence you are seek terminology for the numerators $\,\color{#c00}{6,15,10}\,$ when over a common denominator. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @BillDubuque: Exactly, I am sarching for the terminology (or describing concept) for the numerators $6,15,10$.